# $x=(0,\overline{1})$ and $y=(0,\overline{2})$ generate the same ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

How do I show that $x=(0,\overline{1})$ and $y=(0,\overline{2})$ generate the same ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, but that there is no $u\in R^*$ such that $y=ux$? Working with ideals is relatively new to me, so I would appreciate it if somebody could show me the proof for this.

Comment: The statement is wrong. There is an invertible $u$ such that $y=ux$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Which one? Because the exercise says this

Answer (score 2):

Both 1 and 2 are generators of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. That should be enough for first part.

And as mentioned in comment by @AmitaiYuval, second statement is not true since $(1,3)(0,2)=(0,1)$.

Comment: How do I prove that both 1 and 2 generate that?

Comment: $m$ is generator of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $(m,n)=1$.